# How to create a collapsible list?

Tags: php, jquery, css

Is there a way I can have collapsible list and have the clicked list expand when clicked and stay expanded even when the page refreshes?

I'm using PHP, CSS and Jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called an accordion, and there is one in jQuery UI : http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion